# C# close openned RDP session by user name or session id

Tags: c#, session, wmi, rdp

Is there any way to close openned RDP session from C# application, if I have all users list from WMI?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the `Interop.MSTSCLib` library and it's so easy to use.
Just add `Interop.MSTSCLib` and `AxInterop.MSTSCLib` and then:

to connect:

```
IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
rdp.Connect();
```

and for disconnect:

```
rdp.Disconnect();
```